# Prove if $f(x) = \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ then $f(2)+f(3)+f(4)=\ln(5/8)$

Tags: logarithms

I have that:

> $$f(x) = \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

I need to prove that $f(2)+f(3)+f(4)=\ln\left(\frac58\right)$

Indeed, I proved that $f(2)+f(3)+f(4)=\ln(3/4)+\ln(8/9)+\ln(15/16)$ But couldn't derive $\ln(5/8)$ using it.

Any hint is welcome!

Comment: I think it should be $\ln(5/8)$.

Comment: ah yes you're right! 5/8

Comment: Use $\ln a+\ln b=\ln(ab)$.

Comment: Ah thank you David I solved it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\ln\left(1-\dfrac1{x^2}\right)=\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(2)=\ln\left(\dfrac34\right)\quad f(3)=\ln\left(\dfrac{8}{9}\right)\quad f(4)=\ln\left(\dfrac{15}{16}\right)$$

> **Property $\bf1$:** $$\log{(ab)}=\log(a)+\log(b)$$

$$\begin{align}f(2)+f(3)+f(4)&=\ln\left(\dfrac34\right)+\ln\left(\dfrac{8}{9}\right)+\ln\left(\dfrac{15}{16}\right)\\
& \overset{\mathbf{Pr. 1}}{=} \ln\left(\dfrac34\cdot\dfrac{8}{9}\cdot\dfrac{15}{16}\right)\\ &=\ln\left(\dfrac58\right).
\end{align}$$